# Firebase + OneSignal What dependencies do I need?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, google-play-services, onesignal

I'm building an app in Android Studio.

I integreted OneSignal successfully using these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
```

Now I'm trying to integrate Firebase Analytics to my application.
I now have all these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
```

I'm not familiar with the gradle and dependency stuff. I think I red somewhere that the Firebase dependency included the analytic stuff.

**Do I really need all these dependecies, or are there some duplicates/useless?**

[OneSignal SDK integration guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/android-studio-sdk-installation)

[Firebase SDK integration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk)

In this [Firebase Analytics integration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/), they also use this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
```

Which is confusing me right now, because the SDK integration guide doesn't even list it in the *Available libraries list*

**Can anyone clarify this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not duplicate because `OneSignal` analytics can't use `Firebase` analytics

To use `OneSignal` you need to keep:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1'
```

If you need also `Firebase` analytics, you **don't** need to add that line:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
```

**Please** let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1 isn't this for analytics?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: "we recommend starting with the firebase-core, which include Firebase Analytics, but see below for the full list"

Comment: yes @JoRouss, after checking "firebase-core:9.0.0" poem file there is no difference from "firebase-analytics:9.0.0"..

Comment: Could you change your answer for the CORE dependency 9.0.1, this is the one they suggest. I think they just forgot to update the other page that states ANALYTICS 9.0.0